# Verify Signatures on Javascript-Files

Tags: javascript, security, verification

Certainly I'm not the first one to think of this problem. However, the fact that I couldn't find any articles on this issue (let alone any solutions) fosters my suspicions that there is no canonical solution to this problem:

Let's say I have a trusted web-server that serves a web page using HTTPS and the web page loads some third-party libraries from a third-party web-server (such as a CDN, or similar). Now, in principle, there is nothing that stops the CDN from serving some malicious javascript. This is a problem, except, of course, if I could verify the authenticity of JavaScript-Files served from the third-party servers using cryptographic signatures.

Given that I can dynamically load js-files and there exist crypto-libraries nowadays this should be possible. Or am I overseeing something? Are there existing javascript-Libraries that tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially, yes, you can create the signatures yourself at certain point of time, store them on your server, and when your web page is loaded, you can stream the JS files, calculate their signatures, validate them and then ask the browser to use the JS files, if they are valid.

The problem is that if the third-party author updates the library, then your scheme will stop working until you validate the new code and update the signatures on your server.

Also the necessity to load crypto library from your site will often negate the benefit of using CDNs for other scripts.